# A distance measure for intervals in [0,1]

Tags: distributions, distance

We are carrying out an experiment about automatic generation of fuzzy synsets and, as a result of the experiment, we have a lot of closed intervals in [0,1] which  we need to compare (between them and with other expert-generated interval sets). We have tried Hausdorff distance for its simplicity in the interval case:

$d_H(A,B)=d_H([a_i,a_f],[b_i,b_f] )=\max{(|a_i-b_i|,|a_f-b_f|)}$

but we don't find it completely satisfactory because, for example, assigns the same distance to the interval pair ([0.2, 0.3], [0.4, 0.5]) as to ([0.2, 0.4], [0.4, 0.6]). As, in our application, intervals codify degrees of certainty ([0.3, 0.5] meaning "I'm between 30% and 50% confident") it seems that the distance for the second pair should be smaller that the distance for the first one (they have a confidence degree in common, 40%).

I've thought of using some statistical distance between probability distributions, considering each interval as a uniform distribution over itself. For example, I've looked at the Kullback–Leibler divergence:

$D_{KL}(P||Q)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(x) log\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}dx$

but it has the problem that there can be points in [0,1] where both $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are zero.

I know that there exist a lot of such measures but, frankly, I have not the knowledge nor the time to make an in-depth study. So I'm asking for expert help.  Which one do you think would be appropriate to use?

Comment: Since the interpretation of your intervals appears to be subjective (and possibly not even clearly defined), it doesn't look possible to answer this question in any objective way.  If, however, you could provide definitions for what you mean by "confident" so that the interpretation of these intervals could be known, and if you could more fully explain why you are making these comparisons (and how you would interpret and use them), then it might be possible for people to answer your question.